# How to program remote JVM to display on local desktop without X11 support?

Tags: java, linux

I want to run a light java app on a remote server running linux. It is an old machine so, running X slows things down quite a bit. So, VNC is slow because it relies on X11.

Unfortunately I dont have the code for the remote app. The app requires me to press a few buttons to start the process off. It is frustrating because, the only thing I do with X is press those three buttons.

Is there a way to turn off X on the remote and still be able to do that? Can java somehow project its output windows onto the local machine without X11 support on the remote end?

Comment: I guess you can't change the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUI application will not work without X11 support (or Windows on Windows) X11 doesn't have to be slow unless you have a very, very old machine.  I develop entirely on Linux using X11 and a Swing IDE.

A simple test of you GUI speed is to try the Java2D demo which comes with the JDK.  It can be staggeringly slow on some machines, but on a fast machine the "Arc Curves" test can run at 32 frames per second.

My suggestion is to have a realistic exception of what your hardware can do and if its not up to the job, try a faster machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Google "java client server socket example" search](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+client+server+socket+example)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html

Sounds like what you want to do is create a client/server application using sockets to communicate.  The first link above is a  google search to show several examples of how to do this, the second is a specific Oracle tutorial on the topic.

If what you wanted was to be able to interact with a remote application without using X11 or a Remote Desktop Protocol application, well that is a bit more difficult and I am not sure the result would be worth the effort.

Comment: unfortunately I dont have the code for the remote app. The app requires me to press a few buttons to start the process off. It is frustrating because, the only thing I do with X is press those buttons. ... perhaps this is not worth the effort indeed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit heavy-weight, but maybe [SWTBot](http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ) can do it. I guess you'll still need something like [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) on the other end.